# Magento: Get Product Visibility

Tags: magento

How can I get the products' visibility on a loaded product?

```
<?php
     $Product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
     $Product->load($_item->getId());
     var_dump($product_visibility = $Product->getData('visibility'));
?>
```

I've tried this as well:

```
var_dump($product_visibility = $Product->getVisibility());
```

But always just returns NULL

Answer (score 10):

This is the code I used, and it worked on Magento version 1.5.0.1:

```
$pr2test = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$pr2test->load($product->getId());
echo 'Visibility: '.$pr2test->getVisibility();
```

The visibility value is an integer (1-4). You can find out which visibility setting each integer translates to can by checking the constants defined in the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility` class found here: `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Visibility.php`

If you’re having trouble, I would suggest checking your call to `$_item->getId()` to make sure it’s returning a valid product ID. I can’t tell from your post what sort of object `$_item` is, but I seem to recall that there’s a difference between Items and Products. Maybe try one of these:

```
$_item->getProductId();
$_item->getProduct()->getId();
```

Comment: For those away from Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility, the values are 1 => not visible, 2 => in catalog, 3 => in search, 4 => both.

Answer (score 7):

if you want the visibility attribute in a product collection you should do a join

looking at magento product grind code you can find

```
            $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner', $store->getId());
```

so in your code you can do

```
   $prodColl = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner', 1);
 foreach ($prodColl as $prod)
    {
        $v       = $prod->getVisibility();
    }
```

Comment: after that you can use Nick's methods: $product->isVisibleInCatalog() and $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()

Answer (score 3):

Were you by chance working with a product pulled from a collection? Typical gotcha with Magento in that you have to specifically add the fields to select before loading the collection, otherwise the attribute will return null with no error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
 $product->isVisibleInCatalog() && $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()
```

Comment: Nick is right - adding `$product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()` will return the product visibility. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getStatus` method (also there is useful method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::isVisibleInCatalog`).

Comment: Hmm that looks like it'll work but on a simple product set to 'catalog/search' isVisibleInCatalog returns false. Does it take anything else into account such as quantity, etc?

Comment: @WebFlakeStudio: sorry, maybe I misunderstood the OPs question, but _why_ do you think he should use `getStatus()` when he wants the state of the product's current visibility (catalog, search, none, both) only?

Comment: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::isVisibleInCatalog()` method isn't related to visibility field.